# How to refresh a Listview in a Fragment class after adding data?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, android-sqlite

I am inserting data into a Sqlitedatabase. I want those data to be displayed in a Listview in a fragment class. The problem is that my listview doesn't get loaded with the new data immediately. In other words it is not getting refreshed until I go to some other activity and come back. Can any one suggest me  a solution. My codes are as follows:

```
public class SentTaskFragment extends Fragment {
 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>val=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>(); 
public SentTaskFragment(){}
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater1, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater1.inflate(R.layout.listview_header_row, container, false);
        Databasehandler db=new Databasehandler(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        final ListView l=(ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listViewad);
        int count=db.getcounttask();
         Log.i("count task",""+count);
         if(count==0)
         {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Task to Display", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
        else
    {
            if(id.compareTo("empty")!=0)
            {
    val=db.getTaskSent(id);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "arg2"+val, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
   ListAdapter k=new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(),val,R.layout.r,new String[]{"TaskId","heading","status"},new int[]{R.id.textViews,R.id.textViews1,R.id.textstatus});

           l.setAdapter(k);
    }
```

Comment: Get a reference to your adapter and try calling _adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() whenever your data changes/you want your list to add/remove items. I see you've stored it in k; try using k.notifyDataSetChanged(); Let me know if that works out for you.

Comment: I am not able to use notifyDataSetChanged() with my adapter. So any other suggestions?

Comment: Try casting k to a BaseAdapter by ((BaseAdapter) k).notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: It doesn't help. The Listview still doesn't get refreshed.

Comment: How are you adding the items to your listview? I assume the list you wish to update is var l in your code and the adapter is k?

Comment: If i go to some other activity and come back I can see the updated listview. But i want the Listview to be updated simultaneously

Comment: Are you certain calling ((BaseAdapter) k).notifyDataSetChanged(); when your data has changed though? as in when you add something to your 'var' list. There is no point just adding that line of code after you've initialized k :)

Answer (score 4):

put this code after you insert data into your database

```
((BaseAdapter)l.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: I am using SimpleAdapter

Comment: SimpleAdapter extends BaseAdapter; casting should be fine here.